# Cookie expiry must be a positive integer when adding cookie with expiry Maximum java date Aug 17, 292278994 12:42:55 PM

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to add the following cookie with expiry date as Maximum java date Aug 17, 292278994 12:42:55 PM generated from a url to firefox web driver. 
On doing this I get "Cookie expiry must be a positive integer" error. When year of the expiry date is modified, the cookie doesn't seem to work.

Cookie:

```
 {
    {
          "name": "..dbcjjd",
          "value": "1.2.3.4",
          "path": "/",
          "domain": "abc.com",
          "expiry": "Aug 17, 292278994 12:42:55 PM",
          "isSecure": true,
          "isHttpOnly": false
     },
    {
          "name": "..dbcjjd",
          "value": "1.2.3.4",
          "path": "/",
          "domain": "abc.com",
          "expiry": "Jun 22, 2018 4:11:20 PM",
          "isSecure": true,
          "isHttpOnly": false
     }

    }

    Adding Cookie to driver:

     for(Cookie ck : cookieList)                            
    {
         Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(ck.getName(),ck.getValue(),domain, 
         ck.getPath(), ck.getExpiry(), ck.isSecure());                                                                  
         webDriver.manage().addCookie(newCookie);
    }
```

This was experienced in latest firefox 59 version. The same url in lower firefox version provided null expiry.

Comment: What about a no expire cookie or just add 50 years? Whatever you are working on now isn't going to be used in 50 years anyway.

Comment: The cookie generated from the application URL in firefox 59 which contained the maximum java date when tried putting back to the driver in a different session created this issue. When Changed the expiry date adding 50 years, the cookie doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) a properly formatted date has a year field that consists of 4 digits (see below).  It appears that the year you provided causes integer overflow resulting in a negative value for the timestamp.

> ```
>  Preferred format:
>
>    IMF-fixdate  = day-name "," SP date1 SP time-of-day SP GMT
>    ; fixed length/zone/capitalization subset of the format
>    ; see Section 3.3 of [RFC5322]
>
>    day-name     = %x4D.6F.6E ; "Mon", case-sensitive
>                 / %x54.75.65 ; "Tue", case-sensitive
>                 / %x57.65.64 ; "Wed", case-sensitive
>                 / %x54.68.75 ; "Thu", case-sensitive
>                 / %x46.72.69 ; "Fri", case-sensitive
>                 / %x53.61.74 ; "Sat", case-sensitive
>                 / %x53.75.6E ; "Sun", case-sensitive
>
>    date1        = day SP month SP year
>                 ; e.g., 02 Jun 1982
>
>    day          = 2DIGIT
>    month        = %x4A.61.6E ; "Jan", case-sensitive
>                 / %x46.65.62 ; "Feb", case-sensitive
>                 / %x4D.61.72 ; "Mar", case-sensitive
>                 / %x41.70.72 ; "Apr", case-sensitive
>                 / %x4D.61.79 ; "May", case-sensitive
>                 / %x4A.75.6E ; "Jun", case-sensitive
>                 / %x4A.75.6C ; "Jul", case-sensitive
>                 / %x41.75.67 ; "Aug", case-sensitive
>                 / %x53.65.70 ; "Sep", case-sensitive
>                 / %x4F.63.74 ; "Oct", case-sensitive
>                 / %x4E.6F.76 ; "Nov", case-sensitive
>                 / %x44.65.63 ; "Dec", case-sensitive
>    year         = 4DIGIT
>
>    GMT          = %x47.4D.54 ; "GMT", case-sensitive
>
>    time-of-day  = hour ":" minute ":" second
>                 ; 00:00:00 - 23:59:60 (leap second)
>
>    hour         = 2DIGIT
>    minute       = 2DIGIT
>    second       = 2DIGIT
>
>  Obsolete formats:
>
>    ...
> ```

Comment: Is there any way to handle integer overflow resulting in a negative value, as this is generated in Firefox 59 and with lower firefox versions it creates a cookie without expiry instead of maximum java date and allows reusing in different session.

Comment: A cookie is created by the SERVER, not the client browser.  I'm not sure what you mean by _"this is generated in Firefox 59"_.  The browser does not generate cookies.  Where is the Java code in your question running? There's really not enough detailed context for us to understand the issue, let alone help you.